# web3 js. How to get list of all tokens being in an given address

Tags: web3js

- I want to write a function that has 1 input and 1 output. Input is an address and output is the number of tokens that being in that address
- I am very new in web3. is there any one help me write a simple bunch of web3 code to solve this function

[image]

Comment: you cant do that for every ERC20 token.. that is very complicated, hard, and needs enormous resources. What you can do is collect a list of all important token contracts. and when you get an address you check in this list for each contract if the address has a balance

Comment: Thanks. But if a very new token such as ElonShina airdrop to me (the ElonShiba constract is not included in my contract list) so it will not display in my result??? How etherscan/bscscan can do it (the constract list with update). Thank you sir second